# Jersey client unable to connect to remote machine (502 Bad Gateway)

Tags: java, post, curl, jersey, http-post

I'm having trouble connecting to a service that I have running on a remote machine via a small jersey client test I knocked up.

I'm able to connect and POST successfully using cURL like so:

`curl -X POST -T test.txt -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" http://remote-machine:11181/data?start=123`

The service I have set up on `remote-machine` happily accepts this and works as expected, however when processing the exact same URI through my jersey client implementation I am getting the following exception:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: POST http://remote-machine:11181/data?start=123 returned a response status of 502 Bad Gateway
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.voidHandle(WebResource.java:707)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$400(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:553)
```

My Jersey client is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    if (args.length < 2) {
        System.err.println("Usage: " + TestJerseyClient.class.getName() + " <uri> <input file>");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    File file = new File(args[1]);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        System.err.println("File not found: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        System.exit(-2);
    }

    URI uri = URI.create(args[0]);
    Client client = new Client();
    client.setChunkedEncodingSize(16 * 1024);

    FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
    try {
        System.out.println("Sending " + file.getPath());
        client.resource(uri).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).post(stream);
        System.out.println("Done");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        Closeables.closeQuietly(stream);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated regarding why exactly my jersey client, upon being given the same URI as cURL, is getting these 502 Bad Gateway errors.

(I imagine it could perhaps be a proxy issue, but as for getting jersey pick up on them as cURL seems to, I have no idea.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this through use of the `ApacheHttpClient` instead of the standard Jersey `Client`. Not entirely sure of the differences beneath the surface, but it seems that the `ApacheHttpClient` seems to pick up on any configuration and proxies more nicely than the standard Jersey client, which quite possibly one of the reasons it was created.

All I had to change was:

```
Client client = new Client();
```

to

```
Client client = new ApacheHttpClient();
```

and of course update my dependencies accordingly, etc.

Comment: This worked great for me, the dependency is <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId><artifactId>jersey-apache-client</artifactId> and the version you choose should match your existing jersey-client version